# ASP.Net Saving State Across PostBack

Tags: asp.net, postback

I need to save some text across a postback, but I cannot have this stored in a server session because of non-sticky load balancing to an array of servers.

At the end of the postback I have

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Since this is a redirect, I can't set cookies reliably on all browsers, so that is out (and the 4096 character limit could be an issue as well)

The only option I can think of is to use query parameters, but the data being saved may be more than 2048 characters.

Is there a solution to this other than storing the result in a database?

Comment: You could use Javascript or Meta Refresh so that you take the user to a intermediate page and from there do the redirect (client side vs. server side) and then you could use Cookie.

Comment: You could use a state server that is shared by all of your load balanced servers, but this is an infrastructure change that probably isn't doable.

Comment: Does the url have to change or can you use Server.Transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Using Server.Transfer you can set some public property of your source page:

```
public string SomeTextINeed { get; set; }
```

Then once you have your text set, you can call

```
Server.Transfer("myexcitingUrl");
```

And on the destination page_Load method check you text:

```
SourceWebForm1 webform = Context.Handler as (SourceWebForm1);
string someTextINeed = webform.SomeTextINeed;
```

Comment: this sounds good, but after the Server.Transfer, whenever I refresh the page I get a web browser warning about form resubmission and it may cause any action to be repeated, which results in performing the action again. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: No, not that I know of.  The Nature of an Asp.net event is going to cause a form submition.  So you are going to get this kind of thing after using the browsers refresh.  If you need to allow for the refresh then server.transfer is not your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Viewstate might work. Save/retrieve values like this:

```
ViewState["MyNumericValue"] = myNumericValue;
//at next postback
myNumericValue = (int)ViewState["MyNumericValue"];
```

The viewstate is stored in an html hidden field on the page, so to keep the values you would need to ensure an HTTP POST rather than a GET (which will be a problem if you need to say Response.Redirect. Rather post the form from javascript like this:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

If that doesn't work, depending on the size of the page and the impact you are willing to make to your load speed, you could trigger the redirect in javascript rather than the response.redirect. This means that you set the cookies first and then redirect. If the value is too large to store in cookies I would say that it is not possible and that you would need to store it in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Your only proper solution here is to use the ASP.NET Session State functionailty, in fact that is what it was build for.

For your non DB requirement you can simply **use a shared in memory cache rather than a DB in order to store session state**, there are a couple to choose from that already work well with ASP.NET Sessions:

- [Windows AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx)
- [Memcached](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/)

Yes, there is a learning curve, but after you set it up you won't regret it, this gives you a lot of freedom especially when dealing with load balancers and non sticky sessions, it's definitively worth it.